# How I can mute audio from iframe?

Tags: html, iframe

I'm creating a tribute page (for freecodecamp.com) about Elon Musk and I wanted to include his game into my page via  attribute. Is it possible to mute the autoplay audio? My page url: https://codepen.io/auginis/full/BdwBZW/
The game: https://blastar-1984.appspot.com/
Here is the code for it:

```
<iframe src="https://blastar-1984.appspot.com/" width="1000px" height="1000px">
  <p>Sorry, your browser does not support this game</p>
</iframe>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you can use Sachin's solution, go for it, but I'm pretty sure it only works for media elements, which are just `audio` and `video` elements, last I checked ([spec](https://dev.w3.org/html5/spec-preview/media-elements.html#media-elements)). But things change fast, so maybe you're in luck.

If you can't change it at the iframe level, then you're going to run into cross origin issues. If you can control the headers of the app you're embedding, [X-Frame-Origins](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Headers/X-Frame-Options) is your friend. If you use that header to loosen your restrictions on the game's original page, your javascript will need only to look something like this:

```js
var iframe = document.querySelector('iframe[src="https://blastar-1984.appspot.com/"]');
// This code could probably be tidied up, depending on how familiar you are with the game code
iframe.contentDocument.getElementById("muted").checked = true;
iframe.contentWindow.speaker[0].muted = true
iframe.contentWindow.speaker[1].muted = true
```

If, however, you're not so lucky, then the same origin policy might have you beat. In that case, I'd just suggest making a div and replacing it with the iframe when the click "play" (excuse the lazy CSS in the snippet): [example](https://codepen.io/smeltedcode/pen/eEVWMR). That gives you the added bonus of not loading up content before the user wants it (which is good for performance / mobile browsers).

Good luck!

Answer (score -3):

You can mute it by JavaScript.

This is your html iframe use id.

```
<iframe src="https://blastar-1984.appspot.com/" width="1000px" height="1000px" id="iframeId">
  <p>Sorry, your browser does not support this game</p>
</iframe>
```

add your iframe id in getElementById

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    myVid=document.getElementById("iframeId");
    myVid.muted=true;
</script>
```

By using this you can mute audio

Comment: I have to add this in HTML head? Because I added <script> in head and it still doesn't work for some reason.

Comment: why it is not working, are you getting any error or what was happening ?

Comment: The audio still plays. https://codepen.io/auginis/pen/BdwBZW?editors=1100 I include the link to the full code, the script starts on the 5th line, thanks.

Comment: This will not work on iframe. It only works on video tags.